# FindBugs - finalize error

Tags: java, findbugs

I have `finalize` method in my project(I know `finalize` should not be used, but can not change logic now.) FindBugs gives error that `super.finalize()` should be called, but if that is done and `Throwable` is catched (which should not be done either), FindBugs gives another error, stating `Throwable` should not be catched.

I can not throw `Throwable` either, application may suffer.

Is there anyway out?

Comment: You should let it ascent in your program. `finalize` method in `Object` class does not do anything and will not throw you a `Throwable`.

Comment: you mean, `throws Throwable` is just fine?

Comment: Yes. That's the signature of the original `finalize` (the one on `Object`), so keep it at its original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to throw `Throwable` in your `finalize` method. Here is the code of the method you need:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    try {
        super.finalize();
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your telling:

```
try {
    super.finalize();
} finally {
    ... // your code
}
```